# Laravel returning error 419 after updating SESSION_DOMAIN

Tags: laravel

I recently had to set `SESSION_DOMAIN=".example.com"` to be able to access the laravel session cookie from a subdomain `sub.example.com`.

After this, part of the previously logged users started reporting `Error: Request failed with status code 419` on post request (reportedly even after logging in again), others report being unable to log in at all.

I am unable to reproduce this problem. No related exception or errors are logged, however this clearly suggests that it's an issue related to the session and/or XSRF-TOKEN cookies.

How to fix this?
Will flushing all my redis session data, force all users to log out or remove all cookies fix this or make it worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `SESSION_DOMAIN` caused the coexistence of two cookies named `session` in the browser with different domain configurations.

Setting the `SESSION_COOKIE` to a new value and flushing the `remember_token` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem too... I solved in this way

I had 3 roles: admin, business and members so I created the subdomains in vhost windows32/drivers/etc/drivers/host

add in .env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

in config app after url

```
'short_url' => preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', rtrim(env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),'/')),
```

in routes/web.php

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.'.config('app.short_url'))->middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
    'can:accessMemberPanel'
])->group(function () {

//my routes

});
```

in views I used

```
route('members.index', ['subdomain' => 'app'])
```

in my controller

```
private $subdomain;

public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->subdomain = $request->subdomain;
}

public function index($subdomain)
{
     //my process
}
```